# XML schema specifying transformation

Tags: xml, excel, xsd

I have generated an `XSD` file for an `XML` file and it's working when I am exporting data from Excel.

I would like to know if it's possible to specify the `XSL` file in the Schema itself, so that when the `XML` file is created, the `XSL` is already assigned to it.

Is that even possible? Or do I have to do it through Excel VBA code (which I really don't want)?

Thanks in advance,

Yusuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "assign" an XSLT stylesheet you mean adding a PI to the XML document, then the answer would be that you have to do it with VBA code (or any second step tool, as XSLT itself). I don't see this option when exporting an Excel to XML.

Comment: meaning that I cannot, for example, insert a line in the `XSD` file which would add that PI automatically?

Comment: @Yusuf: XML Schema doesn't target serialization (meaning document as a whole, with DOCTYPE, PI, etc.) but element by element content schema. So, there is no way to reference a PI outside root element.

Comment: ok then, thanks for your help.. i'll have to do it through VBA :(

Answer (score 0):

That sounds strange. The point is that you may have different XSL transforms for each schema, to create different outputs from the same XML.

Comment: yeah it may sound strange, but for this particular Excel file, I'd like to already specify the `XSL` transform automatically when exporting, and I will have only one transform.